# sizeWithAttributes Returning Wrong Size with New Line Character \n

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am using sizeWithAttributes method of NSString to get dynamic height of NSString.

My String is @"This is address line1 \n This is address line2"

but the methods returning only size for line1 (before the \n character)

Is there any way to include \n in string size?

Comment: UsingCGSize size = [addressString sizeWithAttributes:
                                              @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:kFontName size:kProductFont]}];

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `sizeWithAttributes` to calculate the size of multi-line text. Think about it. The size of multi-line text is dependent on how much width it has to be drawn in. `sizeWithAttributes` doesn't let you specify the allotted width.

You need to use `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`. Specify a size with a desired width and a very large height. The returned value will give you the required size to wrap the text within the specified size.

One example of its use would be:

```
NSString *addressString = ... // your string to measure
NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:kFontName size:kProductFont] };
CGFloat desiredWidth = 300; // adjust accordingly
CGRect neededRect = [addressString
                        boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(desiredWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                        attributes:attributes context:nil];
CGFloat neededHeight = neededRect.size.height;
```

Comment: Could you please past code sample actually I am using that too but giving the same result with \n

Comment: @iOSRocks I added an example.

Comment: This is also not working @rmaddy :( its also escaping the text after new line

Comment: Update your question with the exact copy-and-pasted code you are trying. Also include the `NSLog` output of `addressString` and the results of the call to `boundingRectWithSize`.

Comment: @rmaddy You just saved my day! I was wondering why my TextSticker doesn't line break/word wrap and I was using sizeWithAttributes. I went through the docs, but it's not mentioned there ....